# cypress - get return of chain method with page objects

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cypress, pageobjects, method-chaining

I implemented page objects with some chain methods.

Page  looks like this

```
class Table {
    getTable() {
       return cy.get('table#tblItem');
    }

    getListRow() {
       return this.getTable()
           .within(($tbl) => {
               cy.get('tbody').scrollTo('bottom', { ensureScrollable: false, duration: 1000 });
               return cy.wrap($tbl).find('tbody#itemBody tr');
        });
   }
}
```

And in cypress spec file, I do assertion to verify if the row list has items

```
Table.getListRow()
     .then((lstRowItem) => {
           expect(lstRowItem).have.length.greaterThan(1);
     })
```

But I always get the result of method 'getTable()', not 'getListRow()'. The test failed because it gets value 1 of the table.

How can I get correct return of this chain method.

Thank you

Comment: In your code `Table` is a class, not an instance and `getListRow()` is a method on an instance.  You need to create a Table object as in `const t = new Table()`.  Then, you can call `t.getListRow()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The <Table> is actually an instance I declared before. The above is just a draft snip code version. Sorry for the confusing.

Comment: The issue is the ".within()" command which does not allow to change subject as @Fody's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.within()` command will not permit returning of the inner value.

Use a `.then()` and `.find()` instead.

```js
getListRow() {
  return this.getTable()
    .then($tbl => {
      return cy.wrap($tbl).find('tbody')
        .scrollTo('bottom', { ensureScrollable: false, duration: 1000 })
        .then(() => {
          return cy.wrap($tbl).find('tbody#itemBody tr');
        });
   })
```

Ref: [.within()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within#Yields)

> .within() yields the same subject it was given from the previous command.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I missed this ".within()" behavior.
Changed to use ".then()" solves my error.